# Output slim to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm using `Base64.encode64(val)` to convert html to base64.
Example:

```
- val = link_to 'Link', link_path
= Base64.encode64(val)
```

But how can I get slim markup to variable? Like so:

```
.class = link_to 'Link', link_path # <- this output with slim div
```

Or even multiple lines

```
div
span
.another_div
```

There is a way by putting slim code into partial and do this:

```
- var = render 'partial'
= Base64.encode64(var) # Convert into base64
```

How to do this without partial?

Comment: You're trying to render a string containing slim markup instead of a file, correct?

Comment: @wolfemm Render to var, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slim [exposes its templating through the Tilt interface](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#tilt), like so:

```
# Render a template file:
Slim::Template.new("template.slim", options).render(scope)

# Render a string:
Slim::Template.new(options) { "b slim markup" }.render(scope)
```

Where *options* is an optional hash of [options](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#available-options) for slim and *scope* is the object in which the template code is executed.

So the following:

```
slim_markup = <<-SLIM
  div
  span
  .another_div
SLIM

# The options hash and scope have been omitted for the sake of simplicity
html_output = Slim::Template.new { slim_markup }.render
```

Sets the value of `html_output` to:

```
<div></div>
<span></span>
<div class="another_div"></div>
```

But for your example with the url helper *link_path*, you must provide slim a scope in which the url helpers are available e.g. a controller.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I have wondered about this many times, and I always spend a lot of time researching it.

Using Slim 4 you can use `capture` directly:

```rb
- val = capture
  div
  span
  .another_div
```

This will put the rendered slim into your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way from the box using `capture` method. From the docs:

Using the Binding you can capture to local variables as follows:

```
module Helpers
  def capture_to_local(var, &block)
    set_var = block.binding.eval("lambda {|x| #{var} = x }")
    # In Rails we have to use capture!
    # If we are using Slim without a framework (Plain Tilt),
    # you can just yield to get the captured block.
    set_var.call(defined?(::Rails) ? capture(&block) : yield)
  end
end
```

The helper can then be used in the Slim template as follows

```
/ The captured_content variable must be known by the Binding beforehand.
= capture_to_local captured_content=:captured_content
  p This will be captured in the variable captured_content
= captured_content
```

Read more https://github.com/slim-template/slim#capturing-to-local-variables